# make text ignore image positioning

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website for a friend, and she wants me to have an image of her character holding a box over new posts.

Here is how the page looks.

[image]

But, you see the image dis-places the text in a way that is unappealing, and I am wondering if there is a way to make it so this does not occur.

this is what my HTML looks like:

```html
<img src="imgs/meuliboxklok.png" height="200" margin-bottom="70em" align="left"  class="side-image" />
<div class="post">
  <div align="left" >
    <!-- post title here -->
    <h1>&emsp;&emsp;<u>QUUX</u></h1>
  </div>

  <div style="font-size:18px">
    <!-- post body here -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultricies commodo ultricies. Nullam eleifend aliquet mauris eu interdum. Morbi ac mauris nec metus rutrum malesuada eget a libero.</p>
  </div>
```

and this is what my CSS looks like:

```css
.side-image {
  float:left;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: relative;
  top:-90px;
}

.post {
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #181212;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red; 
}

.post h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.side-image {   
  float:left;   
  margin-left: -40px;   
  position: relative;   
  top:-90px; 
}
```

If anyone can direct me towards a solution, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough code.  The `side-image` CSS isn't included.

Comment: Also, it's best to say how you want it to look.  We only know how you **don't** want it to look  :D

Comment: Guessing a bit, `clear: left;` in your `.post` CSS might do what you want.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough, friends. The CSS code for ```side-image``` is: 
```.side-image {
  float:left;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: relative;
  top:-90px;
}``` and I want the top 3 lines not to be indented in the way they are.

Comment: OK, please edit your question to add the `.side-image {` line to your CSS.  I think that's all that's missing.  And let us know if the `cliear: left;` works.

Comment: ```clear: left;``` definitely helped achieve the layout I was looking for. Thank you for the help, good sirs. I hope good fortune will come across you in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

I took a screen shot of your 'new post' image so it's kind of cut off, but I think this is what you want. See snippet below...

```css
 body {
      background:#121D2D;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 72px;
    }

    .box {
     margin: 0 auto;
      width: 750px;
      height: 350px;
      padding: 42px;
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      background: #2B3239;
      border: 2px solid red;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .image img {
      position: absolute;
      top: -65px;
      left: -35px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    h1 {
      padding: 6px 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxbnW.png" /></div>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac imperdiet ex. Aliquam rutrum porta nisi sed feugiat. Nullam vitae ipsum cursus, sollicitudin mi id, consectetur lorem. Aliquam ipsum leo, tincidunt in pellentesque et, suscipit ac felis. Nunc eget est condimentum, aliquet ipsum sed, vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse malesuada egestas convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris congue imperdiet dui, non facilisis neque sollicitudin sed. Sed nec interdum diam. Aliquam risus tellus, tempor vitae massa quis, consequat interdum lectus. Vivamus tincidunt magna ac dui ultricies mollis. Proin euismod at erat id convallis. Cras dictum hendrerit risus, vel molestie tortor tincidunt a. Sed congue eleifendc lectus et sodales. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac imperdiet ex. Aliquam rutrum porta nisi sed feugiat. Nullam vitae ipsum cursus, sollicitudin mi id, consectetur lorem. Aliquam ipsum leo, tincidunt in pellentesque et, suscipit ac felis. Nunc eget est condimentum, aliquet ipsum sed, vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse malesuada egestas convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris congue imperdiet dui, non facilisis neque sollicitudin sed. Sed nec interdum diam. Aliquam risus tellus, tempor vitae massa quis, consequat interdum lectus. Vivamus tincidunt magna ac dui ultricies mollis. Proin euismod at erat id convallis. Cras dictum hendrerit risus, vel molestie tortor tincidunt a. Sed congue eleifendc lectus et sodales.</p>
    </div>
  

</body>

</html>
```